# Touch to awake screen only

Tags: touchscreen, sleep, touch

I'm using Android for a HMI touch screen that is embedded in an electrical cabinet.
It runs a kiosk app with a web browser that connects to a web interface. The interface has buttons that does stuff.

The screen is set to sleep after 2 minutes. And is awakened by touch.
But I dont want the touch to activate any of the buttons in the interface, if the screen is sleeping.
So the first touch only awakes the screen and doesnt register as input in the interface.

Is there an app for this? That could extend/replace the built in screen saver.